# How to enter gnome default keyring password after the prompt disappears?

Tags: evolution, gnome-keyring, prompt

Launching Evolution has gnome-keyring prompting for the default keyring password on Ubuntu 16.04. If `Ctlr+Alt+Tab` is pressed during that process, or if the prompt is not answered fast enough, the prompt disappears and the keyring stays locked. Evolution is thus prevented from accessing the remote accounts. How to unlock the default keyring from that situation, without restarting the system?

NB: in that situation, choosing the "Unlock" option on Seahorse when right-clicking on "Default keyring" has no effect, as if the process was hanging in the background, hence the need to restart the system.

Answer (score 2):

Enter "Passwords and keys" in the dash, or enter `seahorse` in a terminal. Right-click on "Default keyring" and choose "Unlock".

(Apologies if my translations are not exactly the same as what you see)

Comment: Thank you. Unfortunately, in the above situation choosing "Unlock" has no effect: the usual prompt does not appear. My guess is that the unlocking process is hanging in the background but I have no idea how to check it.

Comment: Have you tried doing a logout-login cycle?